# Different behaviour of Task vs. Task<TResult>

Tags: c#, async-await

In a console application I use async-await as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Task<Model>
    var taskGetModel = Testcases.GetModel(22);
    taskGetModel.Wait();

    // Task without TResult
    var taskSaveModel = Testcases.SaveModel(taskGetModel.Result);
    taskSaveModel.Wait();
}

public async static Task<Model> GetModel(int number)
{
    var baseData = await serviceagent.GetBaseData();

    var model = await serviceagent.GetModel(baseData, number);

    model.BaseData = baseData;

    return model;
}

public static async Task SaveModel(Model model)
{
    await serviceagent.SaveModel(model);
}

// as for the service methods:
public async Task SaveModel(Model model)
{
    // the method `.ToCommunication` has the signature:
    // public async Task<CommunicationModel> ToCommunication
    var commodel = await new Mapper().ToCommunication(model);
    // Proxy is the interface to the servce (ChannelFactory etc.)
    // the method `.Save` has the signature:
    // public async Task Save(CommunicationModel model)
    await Proxy.Save(commodel);
}
public async Task<Model> GetModel(BaseData baseData, int number)
{
   // NOT a task: CommunicationModel GetCommunicationModel
   var commodel = Proxy.GetCommunicationModel(baseData, number);
   // signature with Task: public async Task<Model> ToModel
   return await new Mapper().ToModel(baseData, commodel);
}
```

In static main, the `Task<TResult>` gives the nice result that the function `GetModel` returns immediately with the `Task` and I can wait for its result to finish.

Why does the Task in `SaveModel` not return immediately?
The `await` in `SaveModel` is already awaited in that method.
Is it because it doesn not have a `TResult`?

Comment: Well what does your `SaveModel` method do? Is it genuinely async? It would really help if you would provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Note that writing an async method whose only `await` is the very last thing is rarely useful - it's just wrapping one async (presumably) operation in another.

Comment: This is not a difference between `Task` vs `Task<TResult>`. It is most likely a difference between how `SaveModel` and `GetBaseData` are implemented.

Comment: I added the service methods that use async-await also. I experienced the behaviour in debug mode.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with either `SaveModel` method. What are `Mapper` and `ToCommunication` and `Proxy` and `Save`? Can you show us the code or reference what library that is?

Comment: You should not be synchronously wait on asynchronous methods like this.  If you had a message loop you'd be deadlocking your program, and even if you're not you're completely defeating the purpose of using asynchronous methods.

Comment: An awaitable method really *just* returns either `Task` or `Task<T>` (or another awaitable type), it doesn't guarantee that it actually *is* asynchronous in its entirety (or at all, it could return a `Task` with an `IsCompleted` state of `true`).  Without seeing what `Proxy.Save` does, `ToCommunication` does or what `Mapper()` is, it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: @Servy Generally, you're right; but a CLI is, in a way, inherently synchronous (unlike typical GUIs). If the methods you're calling are `async` or you want to have the advantage of calling multiple long-running things at once (asynchronously), `async`/`await` has its place.

Comment: @TimS. You can write a synchronous program that does work in parallel; there are tons of ways of doing that, if that's what is needed.  Here, given that the underlying work is largely asynchronous IO, I'd say the whole program should be asynchronous, rather than synchronous, but doing half and have is giving you the worst of both worlds.  The program should be one or the other; either is capable of working.

Comment: @Tim S. I added the signatures further down the line, there is a small difference there. I suspect that my problem lies in nested calls to async-await.

Comment: CLI is inherently single-threaded, that's not the same as synchronous.  e.g. a UI thread is inherently *asynchronous* but has only one thread.

Comment: Given it's CLI, and given you can't exit from main without exiting the application, there seems to be no alternative but to wait in the tasks.  That's what the `Wait` method is for.  That's a red-herring.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. The following code...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Task<Model>
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("1: " + sw.Elapsed);
            var taskGetModel = GetModel(22);
            Console.WriteLine("2: " + sw.Elapsed);
            taskGetModel.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("3: " + sw.Elapsed);

            // Task without TResult
            var taskSaveModel = SaveModel(taskGetModel.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("4: " + sw.Elapsed);
            taskSaveModel.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("5: " + sw.Elapsed);
        }

        public async static Task<Model> GetModel(int number)
        {
            var baseData = await service.GetBaseData();

            var model = await service.GetModel(baseData, number);

            model.BaseData = baseData;

            return model;
        }

        public static async Task SaveModel(Model model)
        {
            await service.SaveModel(model);
        }

        static Service service = new Service();
        class Service
        {
            public Task SaveModel(Model model)
            {
                return Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            public async Task<Model> GetModel(object baseData, int number)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return new Model();
            }

            public async Task<object> GetBaseData()
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return new object();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public object BaseData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Outputs something like

```
1: 00:00:00.0000102
2: 00:00:00.0087409
3: 00:00:02.0321182
4: 00:00:02.0356848
5: 00:00:03.0459510
```

Which is exactly what you'd expect. Maybe your `service.SaveModel` method is not implemented in a truly asynchronous fashion, and does a long-running operation before surrendering control? Here's an example of a bad implementation:

```
public Task SaveModel(Model model)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return Task.Delay(0);
}
```

This makes it output:

```
1: 00:00:00.0000303
2: 00:00:00.0090621
3: 00:00:02.0345882
4: 00:00:03.0362871
5: 00:00:03.0365073
```

Comment: The example you give works perfectly fine and that is also what I imagined how it should work. So I have to investigate further to discover where the difference in behaviour that I see comes from.